# How do the poles of the integrand contribute to a line integral in the complex plane?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The question in the title is somewhat general, so I would like to make sense of the following simple example regarding line integrals and the residue theorem.

Consider the function $f(z)=1/(z-i)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit. Consider the integral of $f(z)$ along the two different contours in the following picture:

[image]

Both contours are composed by a segment of length $2R$, $R\in\mathbb{R}$ centered at the origin and a semicircumference of radius $R$ also centered at the origin.

For the first contour, the integrals along the segment and the semicircumference are:

$$I_{\text{segment}}=\int_{-R}^R \frac{dz}{z-i}=\log(R-i)-\log(-R-i)$$
$$I_{\text{circ}}^{(1)}=\int_{0}^\pi \frac{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{R e^{i\theta}-i}=\log(-R-i)-\log(R-i)$$

(the superscript (1) labels the contour). These integrals satisfy $I_{\text{segment}}=-I_{\text{circ}}^{(1)}$ and this is expected due to the resiude theorem: the closed contour encloses no poles and then $I_{\text{segment}}+I_{\text{circ}}^{(1)}=0$.

Now, if I try to repeat the computation for contour (2) I encounter something I don't fully understand.  $I_{\text{segment}}$ keeps the same functional form with respect to $R$ as in the previous case, the only difference is that now $R>1$. Using again the residue theorem, since this time the pole is enclosed (and it has residue 1) one must have $I_{\text{segment}}+I_{\text{circ}}^{(2)}=2\pi i$, so

$$I_{\text{circ}}^{(2)}=2\pi i-I_{\text{segment}}=2\pi i +I_{\text{circ}}^{(1)}.$$

However, from the integral form $I_{\text{circ}}^{(2)}=\int_{0}^\pi \frac{iRd\theta}{R e^{i\theta}-i}$ I can't see how the extra term of $2\pi i$ is going to arise, even imposing the condition $R>1$.

**Quick summary:** One can easily check numerically that

$$\int_{0}^\pi \frac{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{R e^{i\theta}-i}=\log(-R-i)-\log(R-i),\qquad R<1$$
$$\int_{0}^\pi \frac{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{R e^{i\theta}-i}=\log(-R-i)-\log(R-i)+2i\pi,\qquad R>1$$

How can the extra $2\pi i$ be derived directly by solving the integral instead of using the residue theorem argument?

Comment: Shouldn't $I_{\operatorname{circ}}$ be $\int_0^\pi\frac{iR\color{blue}{e^{i\theta}}\mathrm{d}\theta}{Re^{i\theta}-i}$?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, but the solutions I gave included the exponential. I'll edit it now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to be careful with the holomorphic branches of the logarithm and where they are defined.

The complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
 \int_\gamma F'(z) \, dz = F(b) - F(a)
$$
holds if $F$ is holomorphic in a domain $D \subset \Bbb C$ and $\gamma: [0, 1] \to D$ is a curve joining $\gamma(0) = a$ and $\gamma(1) = b$. The important point is that the image of $\gamma$ is contained in a domain where $F$ is holomorphic.

For the first contour we can choose $F(z) = \operatorname{Log}(z-i)$ where $\operatorname{Log}$ is the principal branch of the logarithm, which is defined in $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. Then
$$
 \int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{z-i} \, dz = F(R) - F(-R) 
= \operatorname{Log}(R-i)-\operatorname{Log}(-R-i)
$$
and
$$
\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z-i} \, dz = F(-R) - F(R) 
= \operatorname{Log}(-R-i)-\operatorname{Log}(R-i)
$$
where $\gamma_1$ is the upper semicircle of the first contour. The sum of these integrals is zero, as expected.

This does not work for the second contour because now the upper semicircle is not contained in a domain in which $F$ is holomorphic. We still have
$$
 \int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{z-i} \, dz = \operatorname{Log}(R-i)-\operatorname{Log}(-R-i)
$$
but for the semicircle we have to choose a different branch of the logarithm. A possible choice is
$$
 L(z) = \log|z| + i \arg z \text{ with } -\pi/2 < \arg z < 3\pi/2
$$
which is defined in $\Bbb C$ without the negative imaginary axis. Then
$$
\int_{\gamma_2} \frac{1}{z-i} \, dz = \operatorname{L}(-R-i)-\operatorname{L}(R-i) \, .
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
 L(R-i) &= \operatorname{Log}(R-i) \\
 L(-R-i) &= \operatorname{Log}(-R-i) + 2\pi i
\end{align}
$$
the integrals for the second contour add up to $2 \pi i$, which is consistent with the result from the residue theorem.

Comment: This is very clear and helpful, thanks. Just a little question for completeness: what's the basis for being allowed to choose a different branch of the logarithm for each of the two integrals and then add the results together? Would it be possible if the two integrals were not the two parts of a closed contour?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is the “composition” of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ then $\int_{\gamma} = \int_{\gamma_1} + \int_{\gamma_2} $ and the integrals on the right can be computed independently, using a suitable branch of the logarithm (or generally, chosing a suitable antiderivative) for each integral.